# "While loop" (contains pointer to array passed into a function) works only once

Tags: c, function, pointers, while-loop, pass-by-reference

I am writing some code in C. Inside the `main` function there is a `while` loop with a function call to `printboard` taking a pointer to array `board`. Inside the function I have got a `printf`, that prints 3 characters stored inside the `board`" array. HoWever inside the function, I have got just a pointer, so I am doing pointer arithmetics. When the `while` loop first executes, it works just fine. However, when it executes again, it does not work. It does not print the letters. Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void printboard(char *boardp) {
    printf("  %c |  %c |  %c ", *(boardp), *(boardp + 1), *(boardp + 2));
}

int main() {

    char board[3];
    board[0] = 'a';
    board[1] = 'b';
    board[2] = 'c';

    bool playgame = true;

    while (playgame == true) {
        printboard(board);
        board[0] = 'a';
        board[1] = 'b';
        board[2] = 'c';
        scanf("%d", &playgame);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `%d` is for `scanf`ing an `int`, while `playgame` is `bool`. You also need to check the return value from `scanf`. See the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) for more info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You pass the address of a `bool` to `scanf()` for conversion specifier `%d` which expects a pointer to `int`.  This has undefined behavior.  A likely explanation is `scanf()` overwrites the contents of the array `board` when writing an `int` to the destination address, causing memory corruption.

Define `playgame` as an `int`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printboard(const char *board) {
    printf("  %c |  %c |  %c \n", board[0], board[1], board[2]);
}

int main(void) {
    char board[3] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };

    for (;;) {
        int playgame;

        printboard(board);
        board[0] = 'a';
        board[1] = 'b';
        board[2] = 'c';
        // read an int from the user, check for conversion success
        // break from the loop if conversion failure or value entered is 0
        if (scanf("%d", &playgame) != 1 || !playgame)
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, [there is no format specifier for `bool`](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=format+specifier+for+bool+in+C) in the C language, for `scanf` (or `printf`).
Although it may not be the case with your example code, if you *ever must* capture the value of a `bool` by using either of these methods (`scanf` or `printf`), define a temporary container of type `int`, then assign the *captured* value back into the `bool` variable:

```
bool playgame = false;
int temp = 0;

if(scanf("%d", &temp) == 1)
{
     playgame = temp;
     ...
```

As implied, this is for general information only, and does not provide a solution for your specific needs.  That is provided clearly by the [other posted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76622369/645128). (+1)